# Is AES(Rijndael) faster than Blowfish?

Tags: cryptography, aes, java, blowfish

I know theoretical that blowfish is much faster than aes. But I benchmarked several algorithms including aes and blowfish for 1MB, 5MB, 10MB etc. files in java 8 platform and bouncy castle library. In every test scenarios aes is faster than blowfish.

I wonder if I make mistake somwhere?

Here is the code :

```
private static final int WARMUP_COUNT = 5;
private static final int FILE_LENGTH = 1024*512;
private static final int ITERATOR_COUNT = 1000;
private static final double BOLME = 1_000_000.0 * (ITERATOR_COUNT-WARMUP_COUNT);
static final private byte[] ivBytes = new byte[] { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
private static final IvParameterSpec ivSpec16bytes = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
private static final IvParameterSpec ivSpec8bytes = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(ivBytes,0,8));

static String[] algosWithMode = {"AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding","Blowfish/CBC/PKCS7Padding","CAST5/CBC/PKCS7Padding","DES/CBC/PKCS7Padding","DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding",  "IDEA/CBC/PKCS7Padding","ARC4", };
static String[] algos = {   "AES","Blowfish","CAST5","DES", "DESede","IDEA","ARC4"  };
static int[] keylenngth = {128,128,128,56,  168,128,128 };


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(ITERATOR_COUNT <= WARMUP_COUNT )
        throw new Exception("iterator count must be greater than warm up count iterator: "+ITERATOR_COUNT
                +" warmup count :" + WARMUP_COUNT);

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    Key key = null;
    byte[] plainText=null;
    byte[] cipherText=null;
    byte[] decryptedText=null;
    long startTime;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000"); 


    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {

        long timeDec = 0,timeEnc = 0,timekey = 0;
        long maxtimeDec = 0,maxtimeEnc = 0,maxtimekey = 0;
        long mintimeDec = Long.MAX_VALUE,mintimeEnc = Long.MAX_VALUE,mintimekey = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long topDec = 0,topEnc = 0,topkey = 0;



        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATOR_COUNT; i++) {



            SecureRandom random= new SecureRandom();
            plainText = random.generateSeed(FILE_LENGTH);


            startTime=System.nanoTime();
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algos[k]);
            keyGen.init(keylenngth[k],random);
            key=keyGen.generateKey();
            timekey=System.nanoTime()-startTime;


            Cipher cipher=null;
            if(k == 0){
                 cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algosWithMode[k]);   
                 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,ivSpec16bytes); 
            }else if(k == 6){
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algosWithMode[k]);   
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); 
            }else{
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algosWithMode[k]);   
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,ivSpec8bytes);
            }

            startTime=System.nanoTime();
            cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            timeEnc=System.nanoTime()-startTime;


            if(k == 0){
                 cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algosWithMode[k]);   
                 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,ivSpec16bytes); 
            }else if(k== 6){
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algosWithMode[k]);   
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key); 
            }else {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algosWithMode[k]);   
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,ivSpec8bytes);
            }

            startTime=System.nanoTime();
            cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
            timeDec=System.nanoTime()-startTime;

            if (i >= WARMUP_COUNT) {
                if (maxtimeEnc < timeEnc)
                    maxtimeEnc = timeEnc;
                if (maxtimeDec < timeDec)
                    maxtimeDec = timeDec;
                if (maxtimekey < timekey)
                    maxtimekey = timekey;
                if (mintimeEnc > timeEnc)
                    mintimeEnc = timeEnc;
                if (mintimeDec > timeDec)
                    mintimeDec = timeDec;
                if (mintimekey > timekey)
                    mintimekey = timekey;
                topEnc += timeEnc;
                topDec += timeDec;
                topkey += timekey;
            }



        }
        double avgEnc=topEnc/BOLME;
        double avgDec=topDec/BOLME;
        double avgKey=topkey/BOLME;
        System.out.println("********************************************************"+algos[k]+"*****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Avg Enc :"+df.format(avgEnc)+" - "+" Avg Dec :"+df.format(avgDec)+"-"+" Avg Key :"+ df.format(avgKey));
        System.out.println("Max Enc :"+df.format(maxtimeEnc/1_000_000.0)+" - "+" Max Dec :"+df.format(maxtimeDec/1_000_000.0)+"-"+" Max Key :"+ df.format(maxtimekey/1_000_000.0));
        System.out.println("Min Enc :"+df.format(mintimeEnc/1_000_000.0)+" - "+" Min Dec :"+df.format(mintimeDec/1_000_000.0)+"-"+" Min Key :"+ df.format(mintimekey/1_000_000.0));
        System.out.println();
        //System.out.println();

    }


}
```

Comment: @TildalWave firstly thanks for reply. But I think if statements does not effect on evaluations. Because I set the startTime variable every operation such as key derivation encryption and decryption.

Comment: You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 6):

Theoretically, Blowfish is supposed to be faster than AES, but not *much* faster. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8009/why-exactly-is-blowfish-faster-than-aes) for some details.

Then there is *optimization*. For a given algorithm, you can somehow define its "top speed" as being the performance achieved with optimal code; but actual implementations are never completely optimal, and how close (or far) they are to optimality depends on the efforts invested in them. AES is big and used a lot; so people who write AES implementations take care to tune their code so that it is fast on most architectures, including the newest. Blowfish, on the other hand, has a dwindling use base, for good reasons (it has 64-bit blocks, which are not large enough to ensure security when gigabytes of data are encrypted with a given key). Thus, one can assume that in a given cryptographic library, AES implementations are more likely to have been optimized and maintained than Blowfish implementations.

Other points:

- Though Blowfish encryption is fast, the *key schedule* (which transforms the key into internal tables ready to process a lot of data) is awfully slow in Blowfish. In your code, you appear to try to measure speed of encryption "as a whole". If you want to measure raw encryption speed, you should first encrypt, say, one megabyte (to make sure that key schedule occurred and all caches have been populated); then measure the speed of encryption of 10 or 100 more megabytes.
- Blowfish is fast because it works over a lot of lookups in a key-dependent S-box (a 4 kB table). In Java, array accesses are checked (the index must fall within the array length), which makes them relatively slower than other operations. Encryption algorithms which are heavy on array accesses thus incur a slowdown factor compared with algorithms which are expressed as arithmetic operations (a typical case is RC4). This *may* explain why a Java-based Blowfish does not seem as efficient (compared to a Java-based AES) as a C-based Blowfish (compared to a C-based AES).
- Modern CPU have [specialized AES opcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set), which imply very fast AES encryption. A pure Java library cannot use these opcodes, but Java may call native code. If your library uses native code to call upon the AES-NI opcodes, then AES encryption will necessarily be a screamer and Blowfish won't be able to compete.

Answer (score 0):

Modern x86 CPUs provide [hardware acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) for AES encryption/decryption, which is [enabled in the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058309/aes-ni-intrinsics-enabled-by-default#comment35237804_23058309). Although Blowfish might be faster in AES in software implementations, hardware acceleration makes it much faster.

By the way, this question should be on Stack Overflow, not here.

Comment: I would have guessed code review instead of SO - the code is working.

Comment: @user2813274 Code Review is for code quality, and Stack Overflow is not just for non-working code. Code quality and the performance of self-written code is not the issue here, it's performance of the employed libraries and algorithms. It should be on SO.